# transitioning an objective c++ codebase to modules

Tags: objective-c++, c++-modules

I am working on larger Objective C++ codebase. Is there any way to migrate this codebase to modules and drop the header/implementation separation (e.g. c++ modules, clang modules, ...)? I am using clang, and the solution can be compiler dependent.